# how to get and auto enter current date in sqlite db in java?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, datetime

I want to automatically enter the date time of the data into the database table. I am using the `Date` field and used  `timeEntry=DATE('NOW')` but when I did a query, the output is `"DATE('NOW')`  instead of the time.

Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the exact lines of code that are generating the database entry?

Comment: Did not quite understand your question - what do you want to insert into the database??? Date, datetime or time? Also for information that SQLite does not have a field type as 'Date'. There's TEXT, INTEGER, REAL, BLOB and NULL types only.

Comment: I want date and time both. hmm.. got that kind of.. but how do I enter as integer ? i mean what function do I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

> - **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in
>     Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic
>     Gregorian calendar.
> - **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01
>     00:00:00    UTC.

SQLite supports five date and time functions as follows:

> 1. **date**(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
> 2. **time**(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
> 3. **datetime**(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
> 4. **julianday**(timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)
> 5. **strftime**(format, timestring, modifier, modifier, ...)

You can replace `timestring` with 'now' to get the current datetime value.

For more information please see [SQLite date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are inputting the value of `timeEntry` via `ContentValues` be aware that these values are properly sanitized resulting in `timeEntry` being assigned a TEXT value & not the result of the function you are passing.

Comment: @Jeans : so what do I do in this case ? (I am doing what you said..)

Comment: @Jeans : do I do a raw query ?

Comment: or you could do a CREATE TRIGGER on INSERT (and UPDATE if you are setting the value when the row is updated also) that automatically sets the datetime when you create/update a row.